# How can I convert date object in to the format (DD-MM-YYYY)

Tags: node.js, express

How to convert the date object in to format (DD-MM-YYYY). Currently it gives the output as below.

```
startDate: Sat Apr 08 2023 18:03:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  
endDate: Sat Apr 08 2023 18:03:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**Model**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;


const AccomodationModel = new Schema({
    
    serviceProvider: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    otherdesc: {
        type: String,
        
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType:String,
        
    },
    price: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    startDate: {type: Date},
    
    endDate: {type: Date},
    
    created:{
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }

},{collection: 'Accomodation'}, {timestamps: true}
);

// Accomodation is the model here
module.exports =mongoose.model('Accomodation', AccomodationModel);
```

```js
route.post('/add-accomodation', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) =>{

    const accomodation = new Accomodation({
    serviceProvider:req.body.serviceProvider,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    otherdesc: req.body.otherdesc,
    location: req.body.location,
    image: {
        data: req.file.buffer,
        contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    price: req.body.price,
    category: req.body.category,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    startDate: Date(req.body.DatestartDate),
    endDate: Date(req.body.endDate),

    });

    await accomodation.save(accomodation)
    
    .then(data=> {
        req.session.message= {
            type: 'Success',
            message: 'Service created successfully'
        }; 
        
        res.redirect('/dashboard/accomodation');

    })
    .catch(err =>{
        const error = mongooseValidationErrorHandler(err);
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({
            message:err.message || "Error in creating"
        })
    })
  
})
```

**GET method**

```js
    route.get('/dashboard/accomodation', async (req, res)=>{

    if(req.query.id){
        const id = req.query.id;
        await Accomodation.findById(id).then(data=>
            {
                if(!data){
                    res.status(404).send({message: "Service not Found"})
                }else{
                    res.send(data)
                }
            
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                res.status(500).send({message: "Error retrieving service by ID"})
            })
    }else{
        Accomodation.find().then(accomodation=>{
       
            res.render('accomodation', {title: 'Accomodations- Leisure Diary', accomodation: accomodation});
            
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            res.status(500).send({message:err.message || "Error on getting all the data"});
        })
    }

 });
```

I want it to display the date model in the (DD-MM-YYYY) format

Answer (score 0):

You can convert given `startDate` and `endDate` using moment `.format()` like below.

```
const moment = require('moment');
moment(startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY").toDate()
moment(endDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY").toDate()
```

More clarification about moment `.format()` visit this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moment-js-moment-format-function/

Comment: Hi, Thanks fir the answer. Could you please tell me where should I add above codes? 
it shows an error "ReferenceError: startDate is not defined"

Comment: You need to use it after getting data from the Accommodation model. Just add in a callback of Accommodation.findById() and pass data.startDate at the moment and format it.